# Docker not exposing the port

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There is a python application which I'm trying to run inside a docker container.
So inside the container when I'm trying to curl I can see the output but when I try to see the output on my host machine using curl it says
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
and I'm not able to see any output in the browser as well

The port is exposed on 8050
host machine is centos 7
firewall and selinux are disabled

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted the docker command / docker-compose file you use.

From what you say, it looks like you used the `expose` option (or, the container was made exposing that port).

I find the name "expose" a bit misleading.
Exposing a port simply means that the container listens to that port. It does not mean that this port is available ("exposed") to the host.

For that, you need to use `publish` (`-p <host port>:<container port>`).

Answer (score 0):

How did you run the container ?

Connection Reset to a Docker container usually indicates that you've defined a port mapping for the container that does not point to an application.

So, if you've defined a mapping of 8050:8050, check that your process inside the docker instance is in fact running on port 8050 (`netstat -an|grep LISTEN`).